# Allow multiple remote desktop connections from same user

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-server, windows-terminal-services

We're just setting up a brand new Server 2008 R2 with Remote Desktop services.

Everything is installed fine so far, we have set it up with 5 CALs per User (not Machine!) and they are activated and running.

The problem / question here is:

**Is it possible to log in with the same user *multiple* times?**
This worked perfectly fine in `Windows Server 2003`

We just want it to start a `new session` on the server with the ***same*** user.

Has anyone of you got experience in that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open gpedit.msc.

Navigate to:

```
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Terminal Services\Terminal Server\Connections\
```

Change

`"Restrict each user to a single session"` to `Disable`

Alternatively make the change via GPO and apply it to the OU with all relevant servers.

Answer (score 4):

I found out another way to change the same settings:

From the Start Menu, type "Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration".

In the control, you will see the "Restrict each user to a single session" setting. Double-click on it and you'll be given a number of ways to change it.

Comment: This only works if you have Terminal Server installed. This won't work on the vast majority of default "limited-to-two" servers with owners who have no plans to pay Micro$oft money for doing something as simple as changing a max-limit from **2** to more than 2.

Comment: The problem here is because of single session restriction for each user, not total number of remote desktop connections allowed. So, this works as intended.